# Как добавить SDK в IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: android, android-sdk

Не могу добавить SDK для приложения, при создании проекта выбрать нельзя, предлогает выбрать SDK вручную.
Но я что-то не могу найти где оно, у меня все лежит в `E:\Android Build\Androidandroid-sdk`, так файлов на 30гигабайт.

Никак не могу найти, где эта *SDK*.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: открытая на скриншоте папка и есть то, что вам нужно.

Answer (score 2):

В диалоге выбора SDK предлагается выбрать не файл, а директорию. В вашем случае - именно ту, которая изображена на скриншоте.

Comment: Так я же и пытался ее выбрать, но не в какую.

Comment: Когда открывается диалог выбора, вы переходите в нужную директорию. Что происходит дальше? Опишите ситуацию подробнее

Answer (score 0):

После установки SDK обычно лежит в "M:\Users\"UserName"\AppData\Local\Android\sdk"